# Postfix won't work. Are MX and A records correct?

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I'm trying to get email in using postfix and mail on Digital Ocean. I can send successfully but I can't seem to receive any mails. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial.

I've set Digital Ocean as name server for the domain, but I'm wondering if I've set the MX and A records for mail up incorrectly.

**DNS Records**

```
TYPE HOSTNAME        VALUE                          TTL(seconds) Priority
A    mail.domain.me  <000.000.000.000> my ip        3600TTL
MX   domain.me       mail handled by mail.domain.me 14400TTL     1
A    domain.me       <000.000.000.000> my ip        3600TTL
NS   domain.me       ns1.digitalocean.com.          3600TTL
NS   domain.me       ns2.digitalocean.com.          3600TTL
NS   domain.me       ns3.digitalocean.com.          3600TTL
```

I'm trying to receive mail at `user@domain.me`.

I've also checked with nmap to ensure that my email port is reachable by other servers.

**Postfix Setup** 
From `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
myhostname = domain.me
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, domain.me, mail.domain.me, localhost.domain.me,$
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried sending the server some test emails yesterday from gmail and got back this error if it's of any relevance.

```
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. 
Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 
[mail.domain.me. 000.000.000.000: unable to read banner]

Final-Recipient: rfc822; user@domain.me
Action: delayed
Status: 4.4.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; The recipient server did not accept our requests 
to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720
 [mail.domain.me. 000.000.000.000: unable to read banner]
Last-Attempt-Date: Fri, 05 May 2017 04:17:05 -0700 (PDT)
Will-Retry-Until: Sun, 07 May 2017 03:44:56 -0700 (PDT)
```

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion solution is,

```
SSH-Login root
type "sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf"
Find line "inet_interfaces = loopback-only" and replace with "inet_interfaces = all"
Save by CTRL+X and hit Y
restart postfix by "sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart"
```

[Thread can be found on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/postfix-mail-forwarding-socket-error-how-to-fix-mx-records)